# Can't open settings, chrome crashes, GUI is not smooth as well

Tags: google-chrome, system-settings, appmenu

I recently reinstalled ubuntu 18.04.3 after attempting to install nvidia drivers, which messed up my monitor. It looks normal now, but I have encountered new problems such as unable to open settings (it just turns black, forces me to sign in), the pc freezes right after I open google chrome forcing me to restart it, and also not a big deal but perhaps worth mentioning, the "show applications" with all the applications does not show the scrolling animation but just brings me to the next one instantly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note the time of a freeze or crash. Look in /var/log/syslog for messages around the time of the crash. Also look in /var/crash for a new crashfile made around that time. Your description suggests that you may have more than one problem.

Comment: I searched in /var/crash and it said 1 crash, even though i had crashed multiple times, and a bunch of random text that I couldn't tell. I also forgot what time I crashed most recently, so I recreated it and here is the first few lines, I skipped the rest because it would have been too long. https://pastebin.com/b1Xq3jJz I got this from clicking the settings icon on the top right. Also, I first tried to crash google chrome but it didn't freeze even though I didnt do anything

Comment: Also, i checked /var/crash there were two files, _usr_bin_pulseaudio.1000.crash and _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.crash in the 2nd one here is the first bit, the rest is mostly a jumble of text. this one showed a different timestamp by the way. https://pastebin.com/cAP1t5uZ

Comment: All that "jumble of text" is your stack trace (or core dump). It's the information that Ubuntu developers need to understand how the problem occurred, and whether it's due to a bug or a misconfiguration or a cosmic ray, etc. It's the answer to "what happened?" which you need to know in order to fix it. You asked how you could fix it....That's the map to how. Still looks like you have multiple problems - you probably want to identify a pattern, and attack the most common problem.

Comment: do you want me to send the whole thing? im not really familliar with it

Comment: No; this is not the place to report bugs. If you got a "report system error" dialog, and agreed to send the crash report, then you have already filed the bug report. I begin to wonder if you perhaps installed the incorrect video drivers again.